# How to get last visited items - sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table like this:

my table name is : `user_viewed_offer`

```
id        user_id      coupon_id
 1           1             65
 2           1             58
 3           1             65
 4           1             65
 5           1             34
 6           1             46
 7           1             24
```

I want to retrieve these ids:

```
4-5-6-7
```

I used `group by` but it returns these ids:

```
"[{"id":"7"},{"id":"6"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"2"}]"
```

my functions:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('user_viewed_offer');
$this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
$this->db->group_by('coupon_id');
$this->db->order_by('id','desc');
$this->db->limit('4');
$data['coupons'] =  $this->db->get()->result();
var_dump(json_encode($data['coupons']));
exit();
```

I think I use `distinct`  statement but I don't know how can I should use it.

Comment: Your query looks fine if you want last 4 ids for user 1 then remove `->group_by('coupon_id')` clause, Or edit your question and add details why you want these 4 ids ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join your table to a subquery which finds the most recent `id` values for each user, for each coupon.

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, coupon_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY user_id, coupon_id
) t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id     AND
       t1.coupon_id = t2.coupon_id AND
       t1.id = t2.max_id
WHERE
    t1.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I see it, `58` is missing :-(

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to retrieve the id starting form the max value in coupon_id

```
select id from user_viewed_offer
where id => (
  select max(id)
  from user_viewed_offer 
  where coupon_id  =  (
    select max(coupon_id)
    from user_viewed_offer 
  ) 
)
```